# Trying to stream videos to only authenticated users using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to stream videos to only authenticated users using php.

Below is the code I am trying, but unable to play mp4 video.

**index.php**

```
  <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
              <source src="http://localhost/video_test/mp4.php" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
```

**mp4.php**

```
$newfile = '/var/www/html/video_test/videos/MyVideo.mp4';

if (file_exists($newfile)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($newfile));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($newfile);
    exit;

}


?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing an ob_clean()?

Comment: @PhilippGrassl  even removed ob_clean(), but still not playing mp4 video.

Comment: You might want to remove **header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));**   as this is only useful if you are downloading it.

Comment: When you open the mp4.php in a browser, do you reach the mp4 file or do you get an error?

Comment: You have the video in a publicly-readable area, anyone could view-source, get the URL and play it regardless.

Comment: @PeterBlue I have removed your suggested statement, but still video not playing.

Comment: @PhilippGrassl when I opened http://localhost/video_test/mp4.php , my php file got downloaded automatically.

Comment: I'm actually doing a project similar to this. When I get back home I'll show you how I did it.

Comment: @PeterBlue Thanks.. Waiting for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm already working on a similar project so I've grabbed some of the code and stripped-out everything bar the essentials :-

The videos are named 000000.mp4 ~ 999999.mp4  and for the time being, put into the same directory as the PHP code (We will move them later).

This is the page that plays the video :-

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<?php // video-play.php
$vid = (int) $_GET['vid']; // Get video ID
echo "<VIDEO HEIGHT='95%'  SRC='video-file.php?vid=$vid' CONTROLS='true'   AUTOPLAY='true'>\n</VIDEO>\n";
?>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You play video **000001.mp4** with **video-play.php?vid=1**

This is the bit that gets the video file and sends it to the browser :-

```
<?php // video-file.php
$vid = (int) $_GET['vid']; // Get video ID
$vfn = sprintf("%06d.mp4",$vid); // Get video file from ID
$ok = true;

// Code to check if user can view video goes here

if ($ok)
  {
  header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($vfn));
  readfile($vfn);
  }
else
  {
  echo "<HTML>\n<BODY>\n";
  echo "<CENTER>\n";

  echo "<H2> Access Denied ! </H2>";

  echo "</CENTER>\n";
  echo "</BODY>\n</HTML>\n";
  }

?>
```

When you have got this working you can move the videos to a directory that can't be read from the Internet (eg /var/www/videos ) and change line 3 in video-file.php to read :-

```
$vfn = sprintf("../videos/%06d.mp4",$vid); // Get video file from ID
```

The reason we use video-file.php is because other wise the video could be played by simply entering http://your-domain.com/000001.mp4 into your browser - bypassing any controls.

When you have got that working, you need to decide how to control access. The easiest way is probably via sessions.

Hope this helps